# reference to library project

Tags: android

I have a project marked as library and a main one that uses that library.
It looks like that everything is fine, the main project's manifest has the activities from the library with the hole name (package.name) but I don´t know how to call to the library classes I import  the mainactivity (import com.example.libreriasuscripcion.MainActivity;) from the library into the main and when I call it like this:

```
@Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Log.d("Juego - onCreate", "en Onclick");
        Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);
    }
```

There is an error: this is the logCat

```
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.juego/com.example.libreriasuscripcion.MainActivity}: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.libreriasuscripcion.MainActivity
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413): Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: com.example.libreriasuscripcion.MainActivity
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
03-21 09:45:00.534: E/AndroidRuntime(413):  ... 11 more
```

Could you please help me?? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was in the way I created the library, via following this tuto step by step it works fine http://es.slideshare.net/ajdgeniz/como-hacer-un-archivo-jar-en-eclipse and it´s really easy. Then there is to import the class you want to use from the library and use as usual because Android recognise them as local

Thanks everybody

Answer (score 0):

If you are using eclipse IDE, remember to include the library with your exported APK file.

Right click on your project, go to property->java build path->Order and Export

Comment: Thanks Robin, I´m using Eclipse. if I go to property->java build path->Libraries my file.jar is in Android Dependencies. to export the apk with the library included is the las step before finish and now I´m still learning how to use the library

Answer (score 0):

if you use library in your project means

1.you need to add the library into build path.

2.go to>project properties->javabuild path0>order and export ->choose your library.

3.make sure to add your library activity in current project manifest file

4.you must specify the full name of your library class 
in your case

```
Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), com.example.libreriasuscripcion.MainActivity.class);
```

Answer (score 0):

I tried as you said but still the same error this is my manifest

```
<application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:name="com.example.libreriasuscripcion.Almacen" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.juego.Juego"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity 
            android:name="com.example.libreriasuscripcion.MainActivity">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.libreriasuscripcion.Almacen"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_almacen" >
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.libreriasuscripcion.Hello"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_hello" >
        </activity>
    </application>
```

and this is how I call to the library

```
@Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Log.d("Juego - onCreate", "en Onclick");
                //Intent i = new Intent(getBaseContext(), MainActivity.class);
                intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
                intent.setClassName(getBaseContext(), "com.example.libreriasuscripcion.MainActivity.class");
                intent.putExtra("code", "795006");
                intent.putExtra("keyword", "testandroid");
                startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
                //startActivity(i);
            }
        });
```

I´m using and application to save data but then I remove it thinking that it was the error and I used share preferences to do it